# Why does mode hopping occur through a change of temperature?

Tags: laser

Why does mode hopping occur when the temperature of a diode is changed?

Why is a similar effect seen when we change the electric current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the semiconductor band gap changes with temperature, and the band gap determines the wavelength of the peak gain. For a single mode LED the mode with frequency nearest the gain peak will lase. As you change the temperature, and therefore the band gap, and therefore the gain peak, the lasing will switch from the previous mode to whatever mode now most closely matches the gain peak.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Why do we see a similar effect from changing the current?

Comment: @User17670: err, don't know! IIRC the frequency changes with current even when you hold the temperature constant, so I'd guess that current must affect the band gap as well.